# NSMutableArray as global var causes crash

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

i have the following in the .h file as global var

```
NSMutableArray *garr;
```

and the below in the .m file

```
- (void)roundone {
    if (!garr) {
        garr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int x = 0; x < 900; x++) {
            [garr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%600]];        
        }
    }
}
```

the problem in calling the var garr in any method however it returns the values in the nslog correctly but when i use the garr in the code the system crash!!! any ideas plz

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender{ 
NSLog(@"%@",garr);
//bubbleSort(array);    // sort the array
int n = [garr count]  ;
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        if ([[garr objectAtIndex: j] compare:[garr objectAtIndex: j+1]] == 
            NSOrderedDescending)
            //#define SWAP(arr, x, y) 
            do {    
                id oldX = [garr objectAtIndex: (j)];    
                // NSLog(@"%d %s",oldX ,oldX);
                [garr replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [garr objectAtIndex: (j+1)]];
                [garr replaceObjectAtIndex: (j+1) withObject: oldX];    
            } while (0);


NSString *element;
NSEnumerator *iterator = [garr objectEnumerator];
while ((element = [iterator nextObject]) != nil)
    NSLog(@"elments %@",element);
```

i dont what to complicate things in the code but the code works fine when the global var is inside the method but does not work when the garr outside the method

Comment: What is the scope and storage management protocol of garr?

Comment: You hopefully meant `NSMutableArray  *garr;` ?

Comment: What is the crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? And by global var you mean it is outside of the @interface section? Also does the code example you put up there work or is it just when you call it from other locations.

Comment: garr is global and roundone is called at the view did load hope this helps thanx

Comment: You should post a minimal example of how you declare it in the header and how you access it when it crashes.

Comment: i did explain more thanks to have a look

Comment: So what the crash is? Segfault? NSException? Also, run `indent` on your code, it's terribly unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You should *declare* your global variables in the header, rather than *defining* them. Mark the variable `extern`, put a definition into a `.m` file, and initialize the variable to `nil`.

Header:

```
extern NSMutableArray *garr;
```

.m file:

```
NSMutableArray *garr = nil;
```

Rebuild everything, and the crash should be eliminated.

Comment: @OracleOracle The `extern NSMutableArray *garr;` needs to be in the header outside the `@interface` declaration - either before `@interface` or after the `@end`.

Comment: i added and NSMutableArray *garr = nil; after the @implementation  but still i have the same problem ,

Comment: i am adding [garr release]; to the end of the method

Comment: FYI man when i added the code in the roundone method to the beginning of the click method everything works fine!

Comment: @OracleOracle To the end of what method did you add `[garr release];`? I doubt that you should be releasing the array. If you release it and forget to set `garr = nil;`, you would get a crash.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16064/discussion-between-oracle-oracle-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: OK what is the the difference between global def of varibales and local defintions sinice it work on local var very well